# How much of my ancestry will match with my brother?

Tags: genetics, dna, dna-sequencing

Recently, my brother ([full sibling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibling#Full)) got his ancestry checked from [MyHeritageDNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyHeritage#MyHeritage_DNA). They have a similar service like [23 and me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/23andMe) and I've [found out](https://www.top10.com/dna-testing/top-reads/myheritage-vs-23andme) that both companies are offering the basic service almost the same, with some add-ons which are different.

My question is that if I (I'm a male) send my DNA sample to either organization, how different should I expect the results to be?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. We expect posters to do some [research of their own](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Have you considered the genetics and tried to work this out yourself? What do you expect? If you tell us we can tell you if your logic is correct or not.

Comment: Should match pretty well. Are you a boy or a girl?

Answer (score 2):

As both you and your full sibling are males, it means that you share the exact same Y chromosome. You also share the same [mtDNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_DNA) as you have the same mother. All the rest is just a bit of segregation and recombination that will lead to minor differences but generally speaking, your ancestry data should be very similar. Specific disease related data might vary though.